# How do I put Links in between two images html?

Tags: html, css

I'm totally new to html/css so I am litlle confused with one problem. I have an html/css file with a bunch of different links and two images. I need to position them all like this:
[image]

This may be an easy task but for a begginer like me it seems too difficult. I've browsed the Internet on how to do it, but apparently nothing from that fits me. Only thing I could do is position one image to the left and the links to the center of that image but that was not what i wanted. Any help is appreciated!
This is the code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <img src="/image.png">
        <img src="/image2.png">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/states}">Link1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/capitals}">Link2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/events}">Link3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/wars}">Link4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/figures}">Link5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/governors}">Link6</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="h2" th:href="@{/statistics}">Link7</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check out the bootstrap grid system - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ - you can get started here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template - i've linked the previous version since it is the last one with the template (they intend for you to use a bundler with subsequent versions)

Comment: We cannot convert an image into HTML and CSS, despite what you may have heard. Please, share your "*[mcve]*" code, not pictures of the end result you're hoping for (though that is useful information, but first we need to see what's happening, which requires code).

Comment: Feel free to click the checkmark next to my answer if you found it helpful :) this will mark it as accepted so others know your problem has been solved

Comment: I have seen, and edited, your answer at this point. You're perfectly free to disagree, but while we can post an answer saying "this is one way to do it" we can't explain the flaws in OP's original approach without seeing that approach, which limits the amount s/he might be able to learn. It also limits future visitors in the same fashion, since they can't see the starting point.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added what you need, check it out. I also use Thymeleaf, th is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `display: flex`. Here's an example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#text-container a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <div id="text-container">
    <a href="https://google.com">Link 1</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Link 2</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</div>
```

Comment: "*I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate it...*" - as an aside, that's entirely possible here too (for front-end HTML, CSS, JavaScript questions at least).